# How to solve "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_json'" problem?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

I got "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_json'" when I tried to make a function that would give output in JSON file using Jupyter notebook.
Here the code:

```
import json
def ma2(request):
    request_json=json.loads(request)
    nf=main_stat.func(request_json['variable1'],request_json['variable2'],request_json['variable3'])
    return nf.to_json(orient="records")
```

the output:

```
AttributeError   
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-75b494d5499e> in <module>
  9    "variable3":"Chemicals"}
 10 request=json.dumps(k)
 11 print(main(request))

<ipython-input-3-75b494d5499e> in ma2(request)
  3     request_json=json.loads(request)
  4    nf=main_stat.func(request_json['variable1'],request_json['variable2'],request_json['variable3'])
  5     return nf.to_json(orient="records")
  6
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_json'

Comment: This error means that the previous function call returned None, so when you try to call to_json() on that it can't work.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention `main_stat` class but as i can see `func` function at `main_stat` class returns `None`, that doesn't have `to_json` function.

Check **if statements** that returns `None` value. or if you mean it your code could have empty json you must check `nt` value if it's not `None` then use `to_json` function.

```
import json
def ma2(request):
    request_json=json.loads(request)
    nf=main_stat.func(request_json['variable1'],request_json['variable2'],request_json['variable3'])
    return nf.to_json(orient="records") if nt else {}
```